# Erlang installation seems to freeze

Tags: software-installation, erlang

I am trying to install Riak-KV database from source ([see instructions](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/setup/installing/source/) ). Installing it requires lots of prerequisites to follow, though they are poorly written on the site (I apologise if you don't agree). The instructions ask me to install `erlang` ([here](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/setup/installing/source/erlang/)). Once I write this command: `./configure && make && sudo make install` on terminal, it seems it goes on forever. Terminates keeps installing something and never stops.

Is there anything wrong with my command or is there a mistake in the instructions?

My Ubuntu version is 16.04 LTS.

Comment: How much time did you wait for it to get done before considering that it goes on forever ?

Comment: 10 minutes, and it shows me reminder that I have little memory left in OS. Then I terminated the terminal.

Comment: Excuse me if I'm ignorant, but why are you building Riak KV from source when you could [install a binary](http://docs.basho.com/riak/kv/2.1.4/setup/installing/debian-ubuntu/#installing-with-apt-and-packagecloud)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [kerl](https://github.com/kerl/kerl) to build and manage Basho's Erlang.

This build will take some time, and the output should end up looking something like this:

```
$ kerl build git https://github.com/basho/otp.git OTP_R16B02_basho10 R16B02-basho10
Checking Erlang/OTP git repository from https://github.com/basho/otp.git...
Building Erlang/OTP R16B02-basho10 from git, please wait...
DOCUMENTATION INFORMATION (See: /home/sutt/.kerl/builds/R16B02-basho10/otp_build_git.log)
 * documentation  : 
 *                  fop is missing.
 *                  Using fakefop to generate placeholder PDF files.

Erlang/OTP R16B02-basho10 from git has been successfully built
```

Install Erlang R16B02:

```
$ kerl install R16B02-basho10 ~/.kerl/installs/R16B02-basho10/
Installing Erlang/OTP git (R16B02-basho10) in /home/sutt/.kerl/installs/R16B02-basho10...
You can activate this installation running the following command:
. /home/sutt/.kerl/installs/R16B02-basho10/activate
Later on, you can leave the installation typing:
kerl_deactivate
```

Activate it, and verify that it is activated:

```
$ . /home/sutt/.kerl/installs/R16B02-basho10/activate
$ kerl active 
The current active installation is:
/home/sutt/.kerl/installs/R16B02-basho10
```

Git clone the Riak code:

```
git clone https://github.com/basho/riak.git
cd riak
```

Optional: switch to a tag:

```
git checkout -q tags/riak-2.2.0
```

With Erlang R16B02-basho10 active you should be able to run `make`.

You can simply compile:

```
make
```

Or you can make an [Erlang Release](http://erlang.org/doc/design_principles/release_structure.html):

```
make rel
```

A development release (for testing):

```
make devrel DEVNODES=$(nproc)
```

Or a package specific to your OS (.deb):

```
make package
```

See if this has better results for you.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled on this page while was searching for why the Erlang/OTP installation takes forever on WSL.

I had the same exact problem while I was following this article: https://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/install

The installation was stuck at processing some `opt/jit.....mk` file during the 'make' process. The problem is because I was on the `/mnt/` directory. The WSL is slow when writing/reading to the `/mnt/`, thus was stuck. I used the normal `/home/<username/` directory, and it finished in the blink of an eye.

I wanted to post this on this thread -in the hope to help someone having the issue and stumbling on this page.